# Using host JVM to run jar inside a docker container

Tags: java, jvm, docker

I want to bundle an image with a ssh and ftp server as well as a jar file that will run as soon as the container gets started. The problem is that I don't want to have a different installation of the JVM on each image (I will potentially have many instances running on the same host, it will be a waste of resources). So I was wondering if its possible to use the host JVM to run the jar's in the containers.

Thanks!
Rodrigo.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's one of Docker's great parts. You don't install the JVM on your host, but you create an Image that contains the JVM ([or just use one from dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/) ) and base your other images on it. Since Docker uses [AUFS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/) it will reuse the base image and therefore allocate the ressources only once.